# Is every compact simply-connected reductive p-adic group perfect?

Tags: reductive-groups, p-adic-groups, local-fields, compactness

Let $k$ be a nonarchimedean local field and $G$ a reductive $k$-group,
which we assume to be semisimple and simply-connected. Recall that an abstract group $H$ is *perfect* if it is generated by commutators, that is, equals its derived subgroup.

**Question**: Is $G(k)$ perfect?

When $G$ is isotropic, $G(k)$ is known to be perfect. This is a consequence of the solution to the [Kneser–Tits problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%E2%80%93Tits_conjecture) for $k$: the group $G(k)^+$ generated by (the rational points of) additive subgroups of $G$ is the same as the group generated by root subgroups of $G$ for a fixed maximal split torus, and the latter group is generated by commutators. It is known that $G(k)=G(k)^+$ when $G$ is simply-connected.

So the main thrust of my question is when $G$ is anistropic, or equivalently (hence the title), when $G(k)$ is compact in the analytic topology. In type $A$, Platonov and Jančevskiĭ have proved ([On a conjecture of Harder](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=379444)) by computations with division rings that $G(k)$ is perfect. (**Clarification**: This result is for $D^\times$, not $\text{SL}_1(D)$.)

**Related question**: Are there any anisotropic simple $k$-groups not of type $A$?

<strike>I realize that if the answer to the related question is negative then this work of Platonov and Jančevskiĭ answers my first question.</strike> I once looked through the tables in Tits's Boulder notes [Classification of semisimple algebraic groups](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=224710) and it seemed like there were compact simple reductive groups only in type $A$. But this result was so surprising, and the tables so hard for me to follow, that I was not confident in the correctness of my understanding.

Bonus points for questions that work with a more general $k$, say, a complete discretely valued field with residue field of dimension $\leq1$.

**Clarification**: I was too blithe about what happens in type $A$. As krl pointed out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426066/is-every-compact-simply-connected-reductive-p-adic-group-perfect/426080#comment1095360_426066), $\operatorname{SL}_1(D)$ is not perfect, and in fact, its commutator subgroup is its pro-unipotent radical. Riehm's paper "[The norm 1 group of a $\mathfrak P$-adic division algebra](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=262250)" carefully analyzes the situation. So in the end, the answer to my question is "no" overall, but "yes" in many cases.

Comment: The answer to the **Related question** is "no", there are no other such groups, but I know of no better reference than Tits's Boulder notes.

Comment: That's really surprising: there are so many compact reductive groups over the reals. It would be nice to have a simpler explanation of this fact than a case-by-case analysis. Anyway, your comment completely resolves my question, so if you write it as an answer then I'll select it.

Comment: The surprise works the other way for me:  I'm always amazed by the abundance of compact groups in the real case!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you use this fact?  (I needed to know recently general conditions under which all 1D characters of the rational points of a group were trivial, which is the circumstance under which I encountered results of this shape.)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: isn't the answer to the question "no" in general?  Can't one calculate that $[\textrm{SL}_1(D),\textrm{SL}_1(D)] \neq \textrm{SL}_1(D)$ (cf. Platonov-Rapinchuk, Thm. 1.9) ?

Comment: @krl Thanks for the clarification, that was really obvious in retrospect and I didn't read Platonov-Rapinchuk carefully. Too bad the answer to my question is a qualified no.

Comment: My [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/426080) is to your related question, not to the question in the title and body.  I think it would probably be more appropriate if @krl posted their [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426066/is-every-compact-simply-connected-reductive-p-adic-group-perfect/426080#comment1095360_426066) as an answer, and you accepted that instead.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense -- I appreciate your generosity. @krl, I will accept your comment as an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the answer to the **Question** is "no" in general (in the anisotropic case): for example, if $D$ is a finite-dimensional central division algebra over $k$, then Theorem 1.9 in Platonov-Rapinchuk (based on the article of Riehm quoted above) implies that $$[\textrm{SL}_1(D), \textrm{SL}_1(D)] \neq \textrm{SL}_1(D).$$

Comment: Of course you mean a finite-dimensional, central, *non-commutative* division algebra, so that we don't have to worry about the rather boring group $\operatorname{SL}_1(k)$. 

Answer (score 7):

At your [request](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426066/is-every-compact-simply-connected-reductive-p-adic-group-perfect#comment1095276_426066), I post my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426066/is-every-compact-simply-connected-reductive-p-adic-group-perfect#comment1095254_426066) as an answer: the answer to the **Related question** is "no", i.e., all simple, anisotropic groups over a non-Archimedean local field are of type $\mathsf A$; but I know of no better reference than Tits's Boulder notes [Classification of algebraic semisimple groups](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/pspum/009/0224710).

Comment: However, please see @krl's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426066/is-every-compact-simply-connected-reductive-p-adic-group-perfect/426080#comment1095360_426066) indicating that the answer to the question in the title is also "no".